# Display zero's when select Query for Fixed length returns null

Tags: sql, t-sql

I need to get fixed length values from a database table. Below is the query

```
 select cast(TrackID as char(4)) as TrackID ,
 cast(Tracknumber as char(5)) as Tracknumber 
 from Tracking
```

I want to display same number of Zero's when column values are null or empty.

> ```
> TrackID -- TrackNumber
>
> 2121    --   34343
>
> 3423    --   00000
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just do this...

```
 select cast(TrackID as char(4)) as TrackID ,
 isnull(nullif(cast(Tracknumber as char(5)),''),'00000') as Tracknumber 
 from Tracking
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `coalesce()`/`case`:

```
select cast(TrackID as char(4)) as TrackID ,
       coalesce(cast(Tracknumber as char(5)), '00000') as Tracknumber 
from Tracking;
```

The cast is needed so the result is a string, not a number.

A "number" cannot be "empty" without being `NULL`.  If the value is really a string, then you need slightly more complicated logic:

```
select cast(TrackID as char(4)) as TrackID ,
       (case when Tracknumber is null or Tracknumber = ''
             then '00000'
             else cast(Tracknumber as char(5))
        end) as Tracknumber 
from Tracking;
```

Comment: You can use `COALESCE(NULLIF(Tracknumber, ''), '00000')` if it's a string

Comment: @Tim, i need to display fixed length value

Comment: @Gordon, the first one still display empty instead of Zero's for null. The second one has syntax issue "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'end'.".

Comment: @Abdul . . . The first should work for you now.  The issue is that `TrackNumber` is a number.  you need for it to be a string.  An explicit `cast()` is necessary.

Comment: It displays empty where value is null